# How to display a value from mysql database in select-option tag

Tags: php, html, mysql, select

How I can make a `select` tag display the value from mysql table but still have the other options below.

```
<select id="slct" name="psl" class="select" value="' . $row['pslAtOffice'] . '">
        <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
        <option value="No" >No</option>
 </select>
```

I want to see the selected value from the mysql table first instead of the first option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the selected tag to the option, not a value to the select. In your case, this might work well:

```
<select  id="slct" name="psl" class="select">
    <?php if($row['pslAtOffice'] != 'Yes' && $row['pslAtOffice'] != 'No') { ?>
    <!-- This is only visible (and selected) if it's not Yes or No --->
    <option value="<?php echo $row['pslAtOffice'] ?>" selected ><?php echo $row['pslAtOffice'] ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
    <option value="Yes" <?php if($row['pslAtOffice'] == 'Yes') { echo 'selected'; } ?> >Yes</option>
    <option value="No" <?php if($row['pslAtOffice'] == 'No') { echo 'selected'; } ?>>No</option>
</select>
```

You could also do a shorthand if you prefer:

```
<?php echo ($row['pslAtOffice'] == 'Yes') ? 'selected' : '' ?>
```

EDIT:
You have to use shorthand statements if your whole code was wrapped in an echo.
Check out this solution:

```
<?php

$row['pslAtOffice'] = 'Something';
echo '<select id="slct" name="psl" class="select">' . (($row['pslAtOffice'] != 'Yes' && $row['pslAtOffice'] != 'No') ? '<option value="' . $row['pslAtOffice'] . '" selected >' . $row['pslAtOffice'] . '</option>' : '') . '<option value="Yes"' . (($row['pslAtOffice'] == 'Yes') ? 'selected' : '') . '>Yes</option><option value="No"' . (($row['pslAtOffice'] == 'No') ? 'selected' : '') . '>No</option></select>';

$row['pslAtOffice'] = 'No';
echo '<select id="slct" name="psl" class="select">' . (($row['pslAtOffice'] != 'Yes' && $row['pslAtOffice'] != 'No') ? '<option value="' . $row['pslAtOffice'] . '" selected >' . $row['pslAtOffice'] . '</option>' : '') . '<option value="Yes"' . (($row['pslAtOffice'] == 'Yes') ? 'selected' : '') . '>Yes</option><option value="No"' . (($row['pslAtOffice'] == 'No') ? 'selected' : '') . '>No</option></select>';
```

Comment: Great answer, but the problem is that the whole tag is in echo so the if cases are not working

Comment: What? It works just fine, check it out: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bb3710d7bdc575f7463b0389287dc2c839cdd480

Comment: Oh, I see your problem. In that case, you have to use shorthands: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b8359340731f2ba45d30699cedbd0030fdafa244

Comment: Okay But I get an error when I am trying to implement it



 echo ' 
<select  id="slct" name="psl" class="select" value="">
    <option ' .($row['pslAtOffice'] == 'Yes') ? "selected".' value="Yes" >Yes</option>
    <option value="No" >No</option>
</select>';

Comment: That's beacuse of this part: `($row['pslAtOffice'] == 'Yes') ? "selected"`, you missing the shorthand `else` alias `:`... It should look like this: `($row['pslAtOffice'] == 'Yes') ? "selected" : ""`

Comment: When using ternary `?:` operator you must specify all three parts of it (expression, true, false). So even if you don't want to to echo out anything if the expression is false, you must write an empty string `''` here.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for this:

```
<select  id="slct" name="psl" class="select">
        <option value="<?php echo $row['pslAtOffice']; ?>" selected><?php echo $row['pslAtOffice']; ?></option>
        <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
        <option value="No" >No</option>
 </select>
```

Thanks @Balázs Varga for reminding me of "selected"

**EDIT**: You mentioned that the whole block is inside an echo, so I guess it should look like this:

```
echo '<select  id="slct" name="psl" class="select">
        <option value="' . $row['pslAtOffice'] . '" selected>' . $row['pslAtOffice'] . '</option>
        <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
        <option value="No" >No</option>
 </select>';
```

Comment: And you can select it by adding `selected` to the option, and not `value` to the select element.

Comment: @IcedAnt Yes, I was thinking about that but then when you click on the dropdown you will see 2 times YES

Comment: @BalázsVarga. Great answer but how I can check which option is selected. The whole block is in echo

Comment: See my answer ;)

Comment: @EmanuilYakimov If you see YES 2 times, it probably means that the value of `$row['pslAtOffice']` is YES

Comment: @IcedAnt yes I want to avoid that

Answer (score 0):

You need to add database variable (i.e `$row['pslAtOffice'`]) into the first option, not into the select attribute iteself.

Please check below code for more detail.

```
<select  id="slct" name="psl" class="select">
        <option value="<?php echo $row['pslAtOffice']; ?>" selected><?php echo $row['pslAtOffice']; ?></option>
        <option value="Yes" >Yes</option>
        <option value="No" >No</option>
 </select>
```